# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields within an if statement

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to use ACF to output different salary amounts for a job listing board.

E.g:

**Select box option** in ACF for salary type ("competitive", per day, per annum etc). Looks like this:

[image]

Then I have conditional fields. So if "P.A" is selected it shows the P.A field:

[image]

I have a bunch of these conditional fields for the different select box options.

**My question is:**

How do I add these to an if statement so that the correct field is shown based on the content that was supplied?

E.g

```
if job_salary was selected as "competitive" =
   echo "competitive"
 else if job_salary was selected as "p.a" =
   echo job_salary_singular
 else if job_salary was selected as "p.a range" =
   echo job_range_start " to " job_range_end
```

Hopefully this makes sense. This is the code I have at the moment, which just outputs the type of salary entered (e.g, competitive, P.A, Per Day Range) as text.

Comment: Just to clarify... You have five (what I'll call) "top level" options to choose from in the `job_salary_singular` field.  Each of those options *may or may not* hide or show some additional conditional fields.  And ultimately, you're needing to know how to output the proper *conditional fields* with their corresponding "top level" field value in the post (front end of the theme)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach should work. In my example, the main selector field where you choose if it's per annum pay, competitive, a range, etc., is called `salary_type`.

Then I've got `per_annum`. It appearing is conditional on 'Per Annum' being selected from `salary_type`. And finally `per_annum_range_low` and `per_annum_range_high`, both of which are conditional on 'Per Annum Range' being selected.

We can then test based on the `salary_type` selection to output the appropriate values and HTML. Alternatively, you could test for the existence of those fields. But I think this is a bit cleaner and allows you to skip adding an additional field for "Competitive".

**PHP**

```
    <?php

    if (get_field('salary_type')) { //first we check if the salary_type field exists.

        $selection = get_field('salary_type'); //then we store its value as '$selection'

        if ($selection === 'comp') { //we check which selection was made by looking at its label.
            echo '<p>' . 'Competitive' . '</p>';

        } else if ($selection === 'perannum') { //ACF allows you to store a selection as both a value (in this case, 'perannum') and a label ('Per Annum', which is what the user sees.)
            echo '<p>' . get_field('per_annum') . ' per year</p>';

        } else if ($selection === 'perannumrange') {
            echo '<p>From ' . get_field('per_annum_range_low') . ' to ' . get_field('per_annum_range_high') . ' per year</p>'; //and then echo its output and any HTML markup you want.

        } else {
            echo '<p>No Salary Info Given.</p>'; //if they don't make a selection
        }
    }

    ?>
```